# Entity Object not refreshing after many to many .add and .saveChanges (System.NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, repository, entity

I have a many to many entity called VendorReader it looks like this:

```
public partial class VendorReader
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public string AssetValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual AssetReader AssetReader { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository for VendorReader it looks like this:

```
public class VendorReaderRepository : Repository<VendorReader>
{
    public VendorReaderRepository() { }
    public VendorReaderRepository(EventBadgesEntities ctx) : base(ctx) { }
    public List<VendorReader> GetVendorReadersByEventID(int eventID)
    {
        return ctx.VendorReaders
                   .Where(e => e.Vendor.EventID == eventID)
                   .ToList();
    }

    public int GetVendorIDByReaderSN(string readerSN) {
        VendorReader thisList = ctx.VendorReaders
            .Where(e => e.AssetReader.ReaderSN == readerSN)
            .SingleOrDefault();
        return thisList.VendorID;
    }
}
```

In my code I do this:

```
thisVendorReader.VendorID = model.AddEditVendorReader.VendorID;
thisVendorReader.AssetValue = model.AddEditVendorReader.AssetValue;
vrr.Add(thisVendorReader);
```

Which does this in the base repository:

```
public T Add(T entity)
{
    ctx.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

Then I try to do this:

```
model = new MapVendorModel(model.EventID);
```

Which does this:

```
public MapVendorModel(int eventID) 
{
    // steps to create a selectlist
    VendorRepository vr = new VendorRepository();
    listVendor = vr.GetVendorsByEventID(eventID)
        .ToList()
        .OrderBy(x => x.VendorName)
        .ToSelectList(x => x.VendorName, x => x.ID.ToString(), null)
        .ToList();

    EventID = eventID;

    // now let's get the vendor reader list
    VendorReaderRepository mvmVrr = new VendorReaderRepository();
    VendorReaderList = mvmVrr.GetVendorReadersByEventID(eventID)
        .ToList()
        .OrderBy(x => x.Vendor.VendorName)
        .ToList();
}
```

But when I do that I get a Null Reference Exception error on x.Vendor.VendorName b/c it seems the new Vendor added can't be found in the object. I've researched and all I come up with is that SaveChanges is supposed to fix it. This didn't happen before I added AssetReader which stores the actual SN of the Reader (which I need for all sorts of reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an AssetReaderID property to your VendorReader class to go with the navigation property.

```
public partial class VendorReader
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string AssetValue { get; set; }

    public int VendorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; } 

    public int AssetReaderID { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetReader AssetReader { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't want to rely on the default EF Code First conventions then consider also using either [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or alternatively the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to configure the relationships explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

So after working a bit with the Entity model and the Diagram defining an id that I didn't need  and creating a unique constraint on AssetValue and that not mapping and tables changing and all kinds of walls I ended up with a simple solution.

```
                thisVendorReader.vendorID = model.AddEditVendorReader.vendorID;
                thisVendorReader.AssetValue = model.AddEditVendorReader.AssetValue;
                // need to add vendor too (even though we add the vendorID 
                // b/c entity doesn't automatically give you the vendor in a single call)
                vendor newVendor = new vendor();
                vendorRepository vRepo = new vendorRepository();
                newVendor = vRepo.GetById(thisVendorReader.vendorID);
                thisVendorReader.vendor = newVendor;
                vrr.Add(thisVendorReader);
```